# Android game to iOS, go with an engine?

Tags: unity, android, ios, cross-platform

I have developed a game on android using native coding. However I am being asked to port it to ios.

So I thought that I should bite the bullet and recode it in unity so I can go cross platform.

I am just upset that I have to recode everything in unity. Is there any other way or tool that at least will make me use half of my code or so thing? 
Basically what would you do.

Ps:I don't even know unity but I heard learning it is easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is a free game library that supports java and can be deployed to Android and iOS. You will definitely be able to use a lot of your existing code and, depending on how you implemented your Android game, you may even be able to convert many of your draw calls to the Android canvas directly to draw calls in Libgdx.

Libgdx definitely has a steeper learning curve than Unity, but it has a pretty good community and a couple of [good tutorials](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/External-tutorials). Libgdx supports Desktop(Win/Mac/Linux), Android, iOS. It even kind of supports HTML5/JS, though its a bit of a pain to get everything working in the browser.

Comment: Thats a pretty good suggestion. The only problem is like you said the steep learning curve. It's Much harder than unity plus the lack of assets. But definitely a good suggestion and that's why i accepted it

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple way to convert your java code into Unity, unfortunately.

You are going to have to convert the entire code base into either C# or Javascript.  Even the way you do your scenes are going to have to be updated.

There is no easy way around it, sorry to say.

Comment: Thank You.  I am not even limited to unity. I am wondering what would be the quickest and easier way to go to ios. I suggested unity just because I know it is cross platform. It does not seems it is Java to c# conversion. The whole game design will change

Comment: There is no easy way to go from Android (native) to iOS.  Sorry.  Unless someone can prove me wrong, I do not know of any method.